# Plotting odds ratio vs. continuous variable in stata

Tags: plot, stata, logistic-regression

Is there any way I can plot a graph like this in stata:

linear OR of age;

[image]

The odds ratio is from a logistic regression.

I want to plotting the odds ratio of every value of the continuous variable and set reference as the lowest value.
"margins" seems meet my need, however, I have to list all values of the continuous variable so that it can calculate the OR. Another question is I want plot this graph on another graph plotted by "twoway", and I'm not sure how to do this in stata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answer your own question, it's an issue of using `margins` with `marginsplot`. The details are described [in this post](http://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/dae/using-margins-for-predicted-probabilities/), but you would do something like:

```
logit outcome age, or
margins, at(age=(38(1)82)) expression(exp(xb()))
marginsplot
```

For your second question take a look at the `marginsplot` [documentation](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rmarginsplot.pdf). Similarly to other stata graphs it can be combined with other plots.